# description text in a text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, watermark

i want to put some description text in light grey in a text field. then when a user clicks on it the text disappears and he can type whatever he wants.

is there a jquery plugin for this? i dont know what to search for in google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- what you want is relatively simple to do.  Check out the following link:

[JQuery Watermark](http://cysemic.com/2008/12/very-simple-textbox-watermark-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

http://tlporfolio.site11.com/jdesc.html

This is the simplest thing I ever used. Append to a `div` with just one line of code, even set how much times it will display based on cookies. So technically even when you close the browser and open again it count as one time open.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IDofTextField').css({'color': '#aaaaaa', 'font-style': 'italic'});
    $('#IDofTextField').attr('value', 'Your text in here');
    $('#IDofTextField').focus(function() {
        $('#IDofTextField').css({'color': '#000', 'font-style': 'normal'});
        $('#IDofTextField').attr('value', '');
    });
    $('#IDofTextField').blur(function() {
        if ($('#IDofTextField').val() == '') {
            $('#IDofTextField').css({'color': '#aaaaaa', 'font-style': 'italic'});
            $('#IDofTextField').attr('value', 'Your text in here');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please, whatever you do, *don't* do this. The jQuery `$` function is very heavy, and repeating it 9 times when only once will do is almost criminal. In addition, a much better solution would be to define a class in an external CSS file and simple toggle a class on blur and focus instead of doing this.